# Set 100 timers with an interval of 100ms in typescript to execute the code, but the timer execution takes more than 100ms

Tags: typescript, setinterval, publish

I use typescript to implement 100 timers with an interval of 100ms. The execution in the timer only executes publishing data to my local redis. Most of the sending data takes less than 10ms, but there are occasional cases where it takes more than 100ms. I use the same logic code of golang to start 100 timers with an interval of 100ms in the main process, and it will not take more than 100ms.
Below is my typescript code

```
import Redis from 'ioredis';

const redis = new Redis('redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0');

const frameState = "111"

for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    setInterval(() => {
        publishData()
    }, 100);
}

async function publishData() {
    let startTime = new Date().getTime()
    await redis.publish("11111", frameState)
    let endTime = new Date().getTime()
    if (endTime - startTime > 100) {
        console.log("pub data time", endTime - startTime)
    }
}
```

[running time graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwqyv.png)

Can anyone answer this question? I will be very grateful!

I have tried to use golang to implement the same logic, and it will not take more than 100ms to publish data. And I can make sure that there is no problem with the redis server.

Comment: _Can anyone answer this question?_ - this is the only question in your current text. What is your question?

Comment: I guess it's getting reconnected

Comment: @Taxel My question is, in general, data transmission is completed within 10ms, why occasionally it takes more than 100ms.

Comment: @Dimava I don't think there is a problem with the connection, because my program and redis are both on this machine. And the more timers, the higher the frequency and the longer it takes.